# How using global arguments within .resource files in robot framework?

Tags: resources, robotframework

I want to build up a maintainable robot framework environment. Therefore I want to create some ".resource" files with often used Keywords in it. In the ".resource" file is a library imported which needs an argument. But I dont find a way to pass an argument from a ".robot" file to a ".resource" file.

**Issue:**

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/Robustness_yocto.robot' on line 9: Setting 'Resource' accepts only one value, got 2.
```

**".resource" file:**

```
*** Settings ***

Variables   ../instructions/UsbMuxInstuctions.py

Library     BuiltIn
Library     ../library/SerialLibrary.py     _port=${device}  WITH NAME    Device
...
...
...
```

**".robot" file:**

```
*** Settings ***

Variables   ../instructions/DeviceInstuctions.py

Library     BuiltIn
Library     Process
Resource    ../resources/Device.resource    device=/dev/ttyACM0

Suite Setup         Setup
Suite Teardown      Teardown
...
...
...
```

Why is the *device=/dev/ttyACM0* syntax not working and what solution do you would recommend for this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass arguments in resource file imports, but there are alternatives you could try.

1. You can create an **init keyword** for the resource file with arguments, in which you can call the [Import Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Library) keyword to import the library dynamically, during run time. This init keyword could be called in the suite setup. Effectively this would serve as a "constructor" to the resource file.
2. You can leave the import in the resource file and pass a global variable to the library. This global variable could be initialized to some default value but you could override it from [command line](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line) in each run.

   ```
   Library     ../library/SerialLibrary.py     _port=${DEVICE}  WITH NAME    Device

   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   robot --variable DEVICE:/dev/ttyACM0 your_tests.robot
   ```
3. Instead of a resource file you could write a [library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries) in which you can implement the keywords from the resource file, while having the ability to pass arguments when importing it.

   Note that you can import any Robot library from Python as well, and call their keywords, so there is no limitations here.

Comment: Thanks for helping. 

Do I have to call the "init keyword" manually or does a solution exist which calls a keyword during import?

Can I create two resource instances as I can do with "Library + WITH NAME" ?

Comment: @user3129255 You have to call manually.  No you cannot "name" resource files, but  I have added a 3rd option as well.

Comment: Thanks for adding a 3rd option. Libraries have to be written in Python or Java. I cannot use the robot framework syntax, isn't it?

Comment: @user3129255 No, it should be written in Python, using Python syntax.